# Render full_name of a user

Tags: phoenix-framework

Coming from a Rails background I have trouble to understand some basic 
Phoenix concepts. I have a simple app with a `user` model:

```
mix phoenix.new my_app --database mysql
cd my_app/
mix ecto.create
mix phoenix.gen.html User users first_name:string last_name:string \
honorific_prefix:string honorific_suffix:string
mix ecto.migrate
```

I want to display the user in the following way:

```
"#{honorific_prefix} #{first_name} #{last_name} #{honorific_suffix}"
```

Of course only if the attributes are not empty. The empty once are not used.

In Rails I would create a helper (e.g. named `full_name`) which I could call in the erb-template:

```
<%= full_name(@user) %>
```

What is the best way to solve this in Phoenix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In Rails I would create a helper

The equivalent of Rails' helper modules are the [Views](http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/views) in Phoenix. If you're going to be using `full_name` in `web/templates/user/*.eex` templates, it should be in `UserView` (`web/views/user_view.ex`).